# Recursively add to an ordered linked list

Tags: python, list, recursion

I'm trying to create an `add` function to add recursively to an ordered linked list and cannot seem to get started. I'm given the two functions

```
    def add(self, item):
        new_node = Node(item)
        curr = self.__head
        prev = None
        self.add_recursive(new_node, curr, prev)

    def add_recursive(self, new_node, curr, prev):
            pass
```

I know how to add to an ordered linked list in a traditional method but can't seem to wrap my head around how to do it by calling it in this manner as well as with recursion. Other functions that can be used in this class are `.is_empty()` and `.size()`

Thank you

Comment: An important question here is _how does `is_empty` and `size` work_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to hierarchical structures (such as trees), the human brain can easily visualise recursion (we think recursively), but with flat structures like linked lists, this admittedly seems harder to do so.

Let's break this down. At what point should we add a node? Certainly, when we know there are no nodes in front of `curr`. At this point, you'd assign `curr.next = new_node` and return. Until then, you advance `curr` and continue. This is what happens in the iterative sense as well.

Putting this understanding into code, you'd have

```
def add_recursive(self, new_node, curr, prev):
    """ note that we aren't yet taking care of the case when head is None """
    if not curr.next:                
        curr.next = new_node
        return

    return self.add_recursive(new_node, cur.next, cur)
```

One important consideration is the corner case when you are inserting for the firs time. In which case, you'd call `.is_empty` or `size` and check if the linked list has any elements or not, and accordingly assign `self.head = new_node`:

```
if self.is_empty():
    self.head = new_node
    return
```

This is the first check that must be done. So, your full function now becomes:

```
def add_recursive(self, new_node, curr, prev):
    if self.is_empty():
        self.head = new_node
        return

    elif not curr.next:                
        curr.next = new_node
        return

    return self.add_recursive(new_node, cur.next, cur)
```

Comment: That's great thanks you. I forgot to add in my `is_empty()` and `size` functions which are

`def is_empty(self):
        return self.__count == 0

    def size(self):
        return self.__count
`

Comment: when I implement this function, I get the error saying that add_recursive isn't defined

Comment: @JAG Ah crud, forgot to add `self` (also there was another type). See edit, thanks.

Comment: Thought that might be the problem, I assume `cur.next` and `cur` are meant to be `curr.next` and `curr` as well?

Comment: @JAG yes. Do not  add `self` to those since they are local variables. Try this and let me know if it works. Thanks.

Comment: It's adding an item to the list but is meant to add more items as well but I'm still yet to implement a search function so I assume this is what's holding it up. Thank you!